# триггер обновления

Tags: sql-server, триггер

Здравствуйте, задача следующая: нужен триггер, чтобы при добавлении записи в таблицу "Заявка", в этой же таблице обновлялась запись в столбце "Статус" при условии, что если `"дата поступления "<"текущая дата"`, то добавляется запись "В пути", иначе "На складе"
Вот код который написал

```
    USE [ERP]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Заявка_ЖурнаПрих]    Script Date: 08.05.2016 19:33:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER Trigger [dbo].[Заявка_ЖурнаПрих] 
ON [dbo].[Заявка]
FOR insert
AS 
DECLARE @V_Puti nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @NA_Sklade nvarchar(50);
SET @V_Puti = 'В пути';
SET @NA_Sklade='На складе';
if @@ROWCOUNT=0
SET nocount on
IF NOT EXISTS(Select*From Заявка where Дата_поступления < GETDATE())
begin
Update Заявка Set Статус=@NA_Sklade
END
Else
Update Заявка Set Статус=@V_Puti
```

Но у меня возникли проблемы в том что:

1. работает с точностью наоборот, т.е. если дата еще не настала (`Дата_поступления < GETDATE()`)), то пишет что товар на складе и наоборот...
2. Обновляются все записи в таблице.

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: ну вы же update без условий даете, конечно он всю таблицу обновит. Надо же менять только те записи, на которые триггер сработал. По ID записей например. Записи на которых сработал триггер находятся в виртуальной таблице inserted. Вот на основе нее и принимаете решение по каждой записи и меняете при этом основную таблицу

Comment: а как получить id этих записей?через where?

Comment: ну что то типа update Зявка where id in(select id from inserted). только думаю лучше тогда уж переклеится с таблицей inserted и условия сразу тут же в запросе проверить. Ведь если в таблицу вставят с помощью insert select триггер может быть один раз вызван для нескольких записей и для каждой из них условия с датами надо проверять отдельно.

Comment: Спасибо)Все работает)

Comment: @Mike оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте таблицу `inserted` и обновляйте только те записи, на которые сработал триггер.

```
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[Заявка_ЖурнаПрих] 
ON [dbo].[Заявка]
FOR insert
AS 
 update Z set Z.Статус=IIF(I.Дата_поступления < GETDATE(),'На складе','В пути')
   from [dbo].[Заявка] as Z
   join inserted as I on Z.id=I.id
```